# Change system look and feel theme

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

I know I can set System L&F using

```java
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

and change the theme for a certain L&F (*say, "Metal"*) using

```java
MetalLookAndFeel.setCurrentTheme(new DefaultMetalTheme());
```

Is there a way to change the theme (light/dark) for the System Look and Feel?

System Default (On Windows) [image: Light]

System Dark (What I wish to achieve)[image: Dark]

I want the dark theme of the System L&F.

If a dark theme does not exist, I wish to invert the colours of the default theme.

Comment: Just saying, there are third party LAFs you can install which have a dark theme. For instance you can check out [FlatLaf](https://www.formdev.com/flatlaf/). Are you basically questioning if the system LAF has a dark theme?

Comment: @gthanop [FlatLaf](https://www.formdev.com/flatlaf/) is certainly nice. Thanks for the recommendation . Might use it for some other program.

Comment: @gthanop What can I do to draw more attention to this question?

Comment: You can offer a bounty (as you did). I don't know of any other way to draw attention. And I don't know how to answer your question. In upcoming Windows 11 there seems to exist a *dark mode* in the system, but for Windows 10 and earlier I don't know if the system LAF has a *dark mode* at all (or even if this is relevant).

Comment: Oops: I first made 2 long comments mixing this up with another question - both irrelevant. & now deleted. In regard to your question, I don't think there *is* any inbuilt 'dark' PLAF. The only options are to trawl through the [`UIDefaults`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/UIDefaults.html) & reset each color found. The only programmatic way I can think to do that is to provide the 'negative' color of each found. You'll likely see that the result is not what you expect & not pleasing to the eye. But really, just use a nice 3rd party PLAF.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Well, I did create the System Dark image by inverting the colours in the System Default image and it looks decent to me. I am aiming for a look that would seem "native" to the OS being used. Correct me if I am wrong, but third-party LAFs would be consistent across platforms, right?

Comment: *"it looks decent to me"* Huh .. tastes differ, I guess. For my eyes, the difference between the black in the center and the deep gray on the right is not enough to clearly notice. *"third-party LAFs would be consistent across platforms, right?"* I suspect they theoretically *could* adapt to native PLAF but doubt that most actually do. Still, it is likely to offer a better user experience than inverting the colors in the default system PLAF. If you end up deciding to go either way, it'd be interesting to see a report back as to the user frequency of using that option. I expect it would be low.

Answer (score 2):

To change the system look and feel we have to understand how the current implementation of **UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()** works.

The code in  javax.swing.UIManager is

```
 public static String getSystemLookAndFeelClassName() {
        String systemLAF = AccessController.doPrivileged(
                             new GetPropertyAction("swing.systemlaf"));
        if (systemLAF != null) {
            return systemLAF;
        }
        OSInfo.OSType osType = AccessController.doPrivileged(OSInfo.getOSTypeAction());
        if (osType == OSInfo.OSType.WINDOWS) {
            return "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel";
        } else {
            String desktop = AccessController.doPrivileged(new GetPropertyAction("sun.desktop"));
            Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
            if ("gnome".equals(desktop) &&
                    toolkit instanceof SunToolkit &&
                    ((SunToolkit) toolkit).isNativeGTKAvailable()) {
                // May be set on Linux and Solaris boxs.
                return "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel";
            }
            if (osType == OSInfo.OSType.MACOSX) {
                if (toolkit.getClass() .getName()
                                       .equals("sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit")) {
                    return "com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel";
                }
            }
            if (osType == OSInfo.OSType.SOLARIS) {
                return "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.MotifLookAndFeel";
            }
        }
        return getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName();
    }
```

Now for Windows it gets its data from *com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel* . You can find more information about the class in this link ([Open Jdk WindowsLookAndFeel.java](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/sun/java/swing/plaf/windows/WindowsLookAndFeel.java.html)).

The link clearly says  "Implements the Windows95/98/NT/2000 Look and Feel". Package name starts with "*com.sun.java.swing*". I guess chances for getting updates might be meagre and your system might have higher windows version.

To solve your issue we can use many ways

1. Create a new class then extend the above class and override the
   methods. Then you can change default colors.
2. By using Synth—the basis for creating your own look and feel with an XML file.
3. Use Nimbus. As it is very easy to customize it.
   Some info on how to use Nimbus. 
   You can use it to set in *UIManager.setLookAndFeel*  object.

   ```
   try { 
       UIManager.put( "control", new Color( 0, 0, 0) );
       UIManager.put( "Button.background", new Color(18, 30, 49) );
       UIManager.put( "Button.foreground", new Color( 59, 68, 75) );
       UIManager.put( "info", new Color(128,128,128) );
       UIManager.put( "nimbusBase", new Color( 18, 30, 49) );
       UIManager.put( "nimbusAlertYellow", new Color( 248, 187, 0) );
       UIManager.put( "nimbusDisabledText", new Color( 128, 128, 128) );
       UIManager.put( "nimbusFocus", new Color(115,164,209) );
       UIManager.put( "nimbusGreen", new Color(176,179,50) );
       UIManager.put( "nimbusInfoBlue", new Color( 66, 139, 221) );
       UIManager.put( "nimbusLightBackground", new Color( 18, 30, 49) );
       UIManager.put( "nimbusOrange", new Color(191,98,4) );
       UIManager.put( "nimbusRed", new Color(169,46,34) );
       UIManager.put( "nimbusSelectedText", new Color( 255, 255, 255) );
       UIManager.put( "nimbusSelectionBackground", new Color( 104, 93, 156) );
       UIManager.put( "text", new Color( 255, 255, 255) );
       for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
           if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
               UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
               break;
           }
       }    
   } catch (Exception e) {
       System.err.println("Exception caught:"+e);               
   }
   ```

Few more information to customize it.

- [Nimbus parameters and default colors.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html)
- [Nimbus look and feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html)
- [Change Color theme](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/color.html)